# what's the easiest way to put space between 2 side-by-side buttons in asp.net

Tags: html, css, button, space

I have 2 buttons side by side, and I would like to have some inbetween them.

Following code will have 2 buttons right next to each other. I have tried margin for the div, and just couldn't get some nice space between the two.

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="89px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Width="89px" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried margin on the buttons themselves?

Comment: yes, i would just style up a span class (padding-right: 4px; for example) and apply it to the button(s) as a class. maybe i'm missing something here??

Answer (score 96):

create a divider class as follows:

```
.divider{
    width:5px;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then attach this to a div between the two buttons

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="89px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <div class="divider"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Width="89px" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
</div>
```

This is the best way as it avoids the box model, which can be a pain on older browsers, and doesn't add any extra characters that would be picked up by a screen reader, so it is better for readability.

It's good to have a number of these types of divs for certain scenarios (my most used one is vert5spacer, similar to this but puts a block div with height 5 and width auto for spacing out items in a form etc.

Comment: This looks like a very nice solution. Thanks! I had no idea I can learn so much with a simple question like this. :))

Comment: Worth noting: it appears if you have any kind of float going on, the divider will collapse to zero width. If you set min-height:1px that takes care of it, (or toss in an &nbsp; in the content although I'm sure that's less kosher)

Comment: In my case this worked: `.divider{margin: 0.25rem; display: inline;}`

Answer (score 45):

Add a space `&nbsp;` between them (or more depending on your preference)

```
    <div style="text-align: center">         
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="89px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Width="89px" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Like Alex Thomas said in nilma answer. USE CSS.

Comment: It's typically recommended not to use HTML to achieve design goals like this.

Comment: @DerekW could you justify, it does seem to be a simple solution. Is there any optimization concerns or any other?

Comment: @coderkemp: It is generally considered a historical artifact of HTML and CSS is the preferred method these days to address this type of issue. As with many things, there are an endless number ways to do them, but there exists generally accepted best practices based on separate of concerns, code readability, etc.

Answer (score 32):

```
#btnClear{margin-left:100px;}
```

Or add a class to the buttons and have:

```
.yourClass{margin-left:100px;}
```

This achieves this - http://jsfiddle.net/QU93w/

Comment: Yes!  Easier and more reliable than the first two solutions.

Answer (score 17):

```
    <style>
    .Button
    {
        margin:5px;
    }
    </style>

 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="Button" />
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="Button"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

Old post, but I'd say the cleanest approach would be to add a class to the surrounding div and a button class on each button so your CSS rule becomes useful for more use cases:

```css
/* Added to highlight spacing */
.is-grouped {   
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.is-grouped > .button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
Spacing shown in yellow<br><br>

<div class='is-grouped'>
    <button class='button'>Save</button>
    <button class='button'>Save As...</button>
    <button class='button'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try putting the following class on your *second* button

```
.div-button
{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want your first button to be spaced from the div as well as from the second button, then apply this class to your first button *also*.

Answer (score 5):

I used `&nbsp;` and it is working fine. You could try it.
You do not need to use the quotation marks

Comment: There's [already an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119776/2083613) suggesting this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bootstrap, add ml-3 to your second button:

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Button1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-3" type="button">Button2</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another way of doing so:

`<span style="width: 10px"></span>`

You can adjust the amount of space using the width property.

Your code would be:

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="89px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <span style="width: 10px"></span>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Width="89px" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you just just some `&nbsp;` ?

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="89px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Width="89px" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
</div>
```

Comment: Don't do this, please use CSS.

Comment: For screen readers this is a bad idea as the &nbsp; will be considered a character. Use CSS instead

Comment: yes, i was certain that both these answers with the &nbsp would get down-voted. surprise-surprise..

Comment: I did not know about the screen readers, that's very interesting thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the style to apply globally you could use the adjacent sibling combinator from css.

```
.my-button-style + .my-button-style {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

/* general button style */
.my-button-style {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/caeLosby/10/

It is similar to some of the existing answers but it does not set the margin on the first button.
For example in the case

```
<button id="btn1" class="my-button-style"/>
<button id="btn2" class="my-button-style"/>
```

only `btn2` will get the margin.

For further information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 1):

you can use `btnSubmit::before { margin-left: 20px; }`

Answer (score 0):

With the bootstrap CSS, we have a 'btn-toolbar' class.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <button class="btn">Start</button>
    <button class="btn">Stop</button>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/#button-toolbar